# pd.read_parquet produces: OSError: Passed non-file path

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, parquet

I'm trying to retrieve a DataFrame with *pd.read_parquet* and I get the following error:

```
OSError: Passed non-file path: my/path
```

I access the *.parquet* file in GCS with a path with prefix *gs://*
For some unknown reason, the OSError shows the path without the prefix gs://
I did suspect it was related to credentials, however from my Mac I can use *gsutil* with no problem. I can access and download the parquet file via the Google Cloud Platform. I just can't read the .parquet file directly in the gs:// path. Any ideas why not?

Answer (score 0):

Arrow does not currently natively support loading data from GCS.  There is some progress in implementing this the tasks are tracked in [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1231).

As a workaround you should be able to use the [fsspec GCS filesystem implementation](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to access objects (I would try installing it and using 'gcs://' instead 'gs://'), or opening the file directly with the gcsfs api and passing it through.